# .onChange for select2 triggers twice

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, jquery-select2, razor-pages

I'm learning how to implement cascading inputs using Select2 in .NET Core 6 Razor Pages. Unfortunately, I can't proceed due to code that's triggering twice.

Full code:

```
@section Scripts {

    <script src="~/js/jquery-3.7.0.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>

    <script src="~/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/picker.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/picker.date.js"></script>

    <script src="~/lib/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>




    <script type="text/javascript">

        var selectI = $('#selectTableInfo1');

        var selectII = $('#selectTableInfo2');

        $(document).ready(function () {

            selectI.select2({
                dropdownParent: $('#demoModal'),
                minimumInputLength: 3,
                placeholder: 'Select a range:'
            });

            selectII.select2({
                dropdownParent: $('#demoModal'),
                minimumInputLength: 3,
                placeholder: 'Select a range:',
                data: [],  // Empty initial data
                disabled: true
            });

            $('.button-container button').on('click', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var buttonId = $(this).attr('id');

            fetchDataForButton(buttonId);
        });
    });
```

The affected line in question is the `selectI.on('change')` line in the following code:

```
function fetchDataForButton(buttonId) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        headers: { RequestVerificationToken: $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
        url: '/wagetable?handler=CollectData',
        dataSrc: '',
        data: { buttonId: buttonId },

        success: function (response) {

            console.log(buttonId);

            populateSelectI(response);

            selectI.on('change', function () {
            
                var selectedValue = selectI.val();
                console.log(buttonId);
                // Check if selectI has a selected value
                if (selectedValue !== "") {
                    // Enable selectII
                    selectII.prop('disabled', false);
                    //console.log(buttonId);
                    // Populate selectII based on selectI's value
                    populateSelectII(buttonId, response, selectedValue);
                } else {
                    // If no value is selected, disable selectII and clear it
                    selectII.prop('disabled', true);
                    selectII.empty();
                }
            });

        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.error("Error fetching data: ", error);
            // Handle error as needed
        }
    });
}
```

The idea is once a button is pressed, the selectI input is populated with data; next, the user selects an option from said input. Once that happens, the selectII input is enabled and is also populated with data. Once selectII has value, the values from the 2 inputs are used for data population and append the results in a text area.

**Problem**

The problem is that the appended results are displayed twice; some information outright wrong. I didn't display it here because I narrowed down the fault at this line: `selectI.on('change', function () {`. `'change'` somehow gets triggered twice, so does `'input'` as well. `'click'` doesn't do anything.

**Solutions tried**

I've tried changing the line with varying results:

- `selectI.off('change', function () {` just makes the function not work
- `selectI.off('change').on('change', function () {` makes the select input not display any selected value
- `selectI.on('change').off('change', function () {` displays the selected value but doesn't enable the selectII input
- `selectI.on('change', function () {` enables selectII but runs the code twice; meaning I get two sets of data in one run

The last one is not bad on its own, but because `populateSelectII` immediately calls another function that populates a textarea, the displayed information gets screwed. I'm testing the program in Google Chrome. Any advice on how to resolve this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Every time `fetchDataForButton` executes and that AJAX request succeeds, you are adding a _new_ change handler - so they will keep on "piling up." This should not be wrapped _into_ that function to begin with, but handled outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm learning how to implement cascading inputs using Select2 in .NET
> Core 6 Razor Pages. Unfortunately, I can't proceed due to code that's
> triggering twice.

Actually based on your scenario and code snippet, it seems that you have multiple event binders within the `fetchDataForButton` function's success callback. Which causing redundant triggerswhich [@CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe) already been mensioned in the comment.

In addition to this, binding events inside the Ajax success callback might capture additional triggers during data processing or updates.

In order to resolve your issue, you can do as following:

Try moving the `selectI.on('change')` function outside the Ajax success callback, possibly to the `$(document).ready` function. This ensures the event listener is attached only once.

Let's have a look in practice, how you could modify the exsisting code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   
    selectI.on('change', function () {
        var selectedValue = selectI.val();
        console.log(buttonId);
        
        if (selectedValue !== "") {
            selectII.prop('disabled', false);
            populateSelectII(buttonId, response, selectedValue);
        } else {
            selectII.prop('disabled', true);
            selectII.empty();
        }
    });

    $('.button-container button').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var buttonId = $(this).attr('id');

        fetchDataForButton(buttonId);
    });
});
```

**Note:** By moving the `selectI.on('change', function () {...}` outside of the `success` callback, we are ensuring that the event is bound only once when the document is ready, preventing multiple triggering of the `change` event.

Comment: This was the answer! Thank you and CBroe as well.

Comment: Glad to know that your issue has been resolved.